# Função Date retornando dia do mês e hora incorreta

Tags: php, data

Estou tentando capturar a data e hora para fazer a verificação do tempo em que o usuário passou sem efetuar qualquer ação no sistema, porém estou tendo problemas com a função date do PHP. O código está da seguinte forma:

```
$agora = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
```

Porém, ele está retornando o dia do mês e a hora incorretamente. Nesse exato momento são 19:24 e hoje é 14/04, ele está retornando assim: 2017-4-15 00:23:24, ou seja, o dia do mês está vindo com um dia a mais e a hora está vindo 00, não sei porque. 
Gostaria de saber o que posso alterar nesse caso para que a função me retorne a data e hora corretas no formato 24 horas.

Comment: Já verificou o fuso horário no servidor e tentou com [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) ?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, acessei o arquivo de configuração do Apache defini o fuso horário para o da minha região e resolveu o problema, vlw pela ajuda. Depois posta a resposta no campo de resposta para eu já marcar a pergunta como resolvida.